# Breadth-first traversal of binary tree in Rust

Tags: rust

I'm new to Rust but coming from C++ I find the gymnastics of the type system a bit ... troubling. I use problems from LeetCode to teach myself Rust. Take the following definition of a binary tree:

```
pub struct TreeNode {
  pub val: i32,
  pub left: Option<Rc<RefCell<TreeNode>>>,
  pub right: Option<Rc<RefCell<TreeNode>>>,
}
```

Okay, this is a bit ugly already, but I sort of understand the reasons (although it's unclear to me why we can't have a single type that combines the functionality of `Option`, `Rc`, and `RefCell` when these seem to occur together quite often).

Anyhow, here's the BFS algorithm I implemented (it doesn't do anything interesting, the point is the general layout):

```
use std::collections::VecDeque;

fn bfs(root: Option<Rc<RefCell<TreeNode>>>) {
    let mut queue = VecDeque::new();
    queue.push_back((root, 0));
    while queue.len() > 0 {
        // 'pos' measures how far out to the left or right the given node is.
        let (node, pos) = queue.pop_front().unwrap();
        if node.is_none() { continue; }
        let subtree = node.unwrap();
        queue.push_back((subtree.borrow().left.clone(), pos - 1));
        queue.push_back((subtree.borrow().right.clone(), pos + 1));
    }
}
```

My question is: is this really how these things are done in Rust? Isn't there a more idiosyncratic (more concise) way of doing this? I mean, the code uses one of each `unwrap()`, `borrow()`, and `clone()` to get at the left and right tree pointers. This feels a bit cumbersome, to say the least. It might be how things are done in Rust in general, but I'm curious if it's the norm or if it's the exception?

Comment: "it's unclear to me why we can't have a single type that combines the functionality of `Option`, `Rc`, and `RefCell` when these seem to occur together quite often" It is not common enough for the standard library to provide that type. You can create your own, or perhpas there is a crate that does that. Do note however that `Rc<RefCell>` is somewhat considered an antipattern.

Comment: Why is `Rc<RefCell>` an anti-pattern? How else to implement a mutable tree?

Comment: Because it is used many times to bypass ownership, sometimes because lack of understanding. A tree is easy using `Box`; a graph is represented using indices usually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `unwrap()`s here are indeed non-idiomatic and can be replaced. The first `unwrap()` can be replaced with [`while let`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/flow_control/while_let.html), and the second with [`if let`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/flow_control/if_let.html):

```rust
while let Some((node, pos)) = queue.pop_front() {
    // 'pos' measures how far out to the left or right the given node is.
    if let Some(subtree) = node {
        queue.push_back((subtree.borrow().left.clone(), pos - 1));
        queue.push_back((subtree.borrow().right.clone(), pos + 1));
    }
}
```

Having to wrap the whole loop body with `if let` is unfortunate. The experimental feature [`let_else`](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/3137-let-else.html) will solve that (stabilized in Rust 1.65.0):

```rust
#![feature(let_else)]

while let Some((node, pos)) = queue.pop_front() {
    // 'pos' measures how far out to the left or right the given node is.
    let Some(subtree) = node else {
        continue;
    };
    
    queue.push_back((subtree.borrow().left.clone(), pos - 1));
    queue.push_back((subtree.borrow().right.clone(), pos + 1));
}
```

But the `borrow()` and `clone()` are because you try to bypass the ownership rules with `Rc<RefCell>`. This is somewhat considered an antipattern: if you think you need to use that, think again. There may be much more Rusty way of doing things. Sometimes it is simple, sometimes requires a redesign of your data structure (for example, with graphs that are commonly represented with indices in Rust).

A simpler tree will also have a simpler search function:

```rust
pub struct TreeNode {
    pub val: i32,
    pub left: Option<Box<TreeNode>>,
    pub right: Option<Box<TreeNode>>,
}

fn bfs(root: Option<&TreeNode>) {
    let mut queue = VecDeque::new();
    queue.push_back((root, 0));
    while let Some((node, pos)) = queue.pop_front() {
        // 'pos' measures how far out to the left or right the given node is.
        let Some(subtree) = node else {
            continue;
        };
        
        queue.push_back((subtree.left.as_deref(), pos - 1));
        queue.push_back((subtree.right.as_deref(), pos + 1));
    }
}
```

Comment: Newbie question: the type of `queue` appears to be `VecDeque<Option<&TreeNode>>`. How does Rust know that it's okay to store references to tree nodes in the queue? That they are going to be valid?

Comment: @LajosNagy Because they're all derived from `root`, so they have the same lifetime.